# How would one achive this black and white glitch-ish text effect in photoshop or illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, typography, glitch

I've been trying to achieve this black and white  distorted text effect behind the green SUNDAY NOVEMBER 26th letters with no succes.

I'm specifically struggling trying to duplicate the letters in this black and white stripe fashion. They seem to turn gradually into the neighbour letters as they get closer i.e loosing the S letter shape as it gets closer to the U letter.

I've tried distortion effects like shear, and I've been playing around adding several strokes at a time. I've also tried copying and pasting multiple times the same letter next to each other but it gets nowhere near the desired effect.

I apologize for my poor English, I really wish I could explain myself better! I'll try come back and edit as many times as needed. 
Thank you for your time.

[image: text effect]

Comment: Most likely via a plugin.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly the same, or are you happy with some kind of random glitch effects?  If so try this online generator: https://snorpey.github.io/jpg-glitch/

Comment: I finally got a reply from the person who made it. Turns out it was done with data bending techniques. A blurred text that got corrupted made the black and white pattern. Thank you for the replies!

Comment: @mercadona: Please do not answer questions in the comments, even if they are your own. It is perfectly acceptable that you [self-answer](/help/self-answer) your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to show my version.
The result is almost like the image sample (I think).
Using Photoshop CC.

1- Duplicate the text several times. Leave a master copy on top of the layer stack.

2- Select the copy layers and make a Smart Object. Change the Smart Layer to Darker Mode.

3- Filter > Blur > Motion Blur. Angle 0, distance 8.

4- Filter > Sharpen > Sharpen. Repeat it 8 times or something like.

5- Reveal the master copy and give it some color.

I did not test this but I think a lower resolution would give a more jaggy effect.

Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that was originally done with a script and a mathematical formula.

It sounds like you are trying to right way - you just won't be able to do it with the right script.

Maybe look for plug-ins that emulate old video effects?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. I got back from the person who did it and it was made with data bending tricks, apparently.